# How to override U-Boot "bootcmd" variable

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, boot, u-boot

I am trying to compile u-boot for my BeagleBone Black (am335x) and would like to tweak what the "bootcmd" command does. I see that in my [**am334x_evm_defconfig**](https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/v2019.07/source/configs/am335x_evm_defconfig) that there is a config that looks like this:

```
CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND="if test ${boot_fit} -eq 1; then run update_to_fit; fi; run findfdt; run init_console; run envboot; run distro_bootcmd"
```

But when I try to add any change ex.

```
CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND="echo this is my bootcmd; if test ${boot_fit} -eq 1; then run update_to_fit; fi; run findfdt; run init_console; run envboot; run distro_bootcmd"
```

The bootcmd does not show up in my default environment and my echo does not show up when booting. Where in the build process is CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND getting ignored? Or is there another place that it can be defined?

For clarification, I store my environment on my eMMC so I made sure to zero it out so that U-boot does not read any variables from previous compilations of u-boot and uses the default one that it compiled.

Comment: On startup, does U-Boot actually report that it is using the *"default environment"* (as you assume)?  Have you searched for the `bootcmd=` string in your rebuilt **u-boot.bin**  file (in both the build directory and the installed copy on the target board)?

Comment: @sawdust No, I am not assuming as on boot, it says 'Loading Environment from MMC... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment'  .  When doing a grep on my u-boot.bin file(s), I see that my bootcmd is still the original one. Just to make sure I was even recompiling properly, I compiled with some dummy variables which reflected in my .bin and when I do a printenv.

Comment: In which file exactly had you done the changes?

Answer (score 3):

> I see that in my **am334x_evm_defconfig** ...
>    ...
>   But when I try to add any change ...

When you perform any edits to a **xxx_defconfig** file, a `make` command after such edits will not apply those modifications to the **.config** file, so those changes will not show up in subsequent builds.
The only way to get those changes into your next build would require a completely fresh build, that is, a `make distclean` (or `make mrproper`) command, followed with a `make xxx_defconfig`.

---

Rather than directly editing a **xxx_defconfig** file, you would probably be better off making changes using the more reliable `make menuconfig` command, which will respect dependencies.
For **CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND**, there are top-level entries for `Enable a default value for bootcmd` and the command string.
The modified and saved configuration can then be used in subequent builds with a simple `make`, or turned into a new **./defconfig** file with the `make savedefconfig` command.

---

> Where in the build process is CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND getting ignored?

Your changes are only ignored because they have not been applied to the build configuration, which is the **.config** file.

> Or is there another place that it can be defined?

Not a concern if proper build procedure is followed.